# c# / asp.net compiling project

Tags: c#, asp.net, project, compilation

me and a friend are working on some software in which custom variables need to be inserted into the code for each customer. Whe thought about using a seperate text file but for portability and security we want to include the variables into the .exe.

I have looked at tutorials like this one :
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dommym/5598/
or this one : 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

to use asp.net to get the client's data, insert it into the source and then compile it. But these articles only talk about single file sources and our main project has multiple .cs files. So my question was : how would I compile a whole project instead of just one file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use embedded [resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxb70x7.aspx) for this.

You can reference the embedded strings from anywhere in the project.

Comment: Could you give me a example on how to use this ?

Comment: @Quincy - The linked MSDN article and the links it contains have examples.

Comment: Thanks looked at it a couple of times, also tried googling a bit but I still don't get it. Sorry if this looks like I don't know anything about programming but visual studio normaly does everything for me and now all of the sudden I have to do it myself.

Comment: Yes but what to do with it and how can I use it to compile the entire project ?

Comment: @Xyro - How do you mean to compile an entire project? You add resource files, add resources to them and reference the resources. There is nothing more to it.

Comment: Well at the bottom of my question I ask how to programaticly compile a whole project instead of just one file ?

Comment: @Xyro - I don't quite get it. When you compile the project in VS, the resources get compiled as well. Where exactly are you having problems with this?

Comment: Thats not the problem, the problem is, I have a project and I want another executable to compile the project and as I said I looked up some things to compile programmaticly but it only gives examples for single files.